# Execute table-valued function on multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Given a table-valued function such as `dbo.Split()` from ["T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor), how do I pass multiple rows as arguments?

This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split
  (',', (SELECT myColumn FROM Stuff WHERE id = 22268))
WHERE ISNULL(s,'') <> ''
```

It returns:

```
pn          s
----------- -----------
1           22351
2           22354
3           22356
4           22357
5           22360
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split
  (',', (SELECT myColumn FROM Stuff))
WHERE ISNULL(s,'') <> ''
```

Nor does this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split_temp(',', myColumn), Stuff
```

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175562.aspx) say:

> When a user-defined function that returns a table is invoked in the FROM clause of a subquery, the function arguments cannot reference any columns from the outer query.

The sort of result set I'm looking for would look something like:

```
id          pn          s
----------- ----------- -----------
22268       1           22351
22268       2           22354
22268       3           22356
22268       4           22357
22268       5           22360
24104       1           22353
24104       2           22355
24104       3           22356
24104       4           22358
24104       5           22360
24104       6           22362
24104       7           22364
.
.
.
```

Is there any way at all (aside from, of course, a cursor) to accomplish this?

(edit)

As requested by MarlonRibunal, a sample table to produce the above result looks like:

```
id          myColumn
----------- -------------------------------------------
22268       22351,22354,22356,22357,22360,
24104       22353,22355,22356,22358,22360,22362,22364,
```

`id` is an `int`; `myColumn` is a `varchar(max)`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT Stuff.id
    ,Results.pn
    ,Results.s
FROM stackoverflow_454945 AS Stuff
OUTER APPLY dbo.Split(',', Stuff.myColumn) AS Results
WHERE ISNULL(Results.s,'') <> ''
```

Comment: Awesome!

The second "FROM Stuff" was actually marked as a syntax error, but after removing that, the statement did exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Right, I left that in from my copy/paste - I've tested and corrected the code here.

Comment: Why use `isnull(Results.s,'') <> ''` when `Results.s is not null` also works and is a lot more terse?

Comment: @tgandrews They aren't equivalent when Results.s = '' - so the isnull(Results.s, '') <> '' also filters out empty string.  If that's not a possible output, then it's not necessary.  It was in the original question, so I just kept that technique.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Trying to include the rows from a table function call using a subquery (SELECT _ FROM ...) was causing me major trouble when there were multiple results. Well done and thank you for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the COALESCE concatenation behavior

```
declare @split varchar(max) 
set @split = ''

select @split = @split + Coalesce(myColumn + ',' , ' ') 
from Stuff 
WHERE id = 22268

select * from dbo.Split(',', @Left(@split,len(@split) -1))
```

I don't know that that would be any better than using a cursor.

Comment: AIUI, that wouldn't retain the respective id of the row, only the value.