# How can I execute a UDF on multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function defined in SQL Server.  I want create a single select statement that would be able to execute the function on all rows in a particular column.  Is this possible and what would be the best way to do it?

Thank You

I saw this 'Execute table-valued function on multiple rows' and dont believe it answers my question.

[Execute table-valued function on multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454945/execute-table-valued-function-on-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select dbo.YourFunc(column) as result
from table
```

PS: Stop thinking procedurally! It's a set-oriented language :)