# SQL: Remove preceding space from fn_Split results

Tags: sql, split, delimiter

just a quick question.

I found these two articles when looking for a solution to split a string by delimiter.

- [Execute table-valued function on multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454945/execute-table-valued-function-on-multiple-rows)

which lead me to

- [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco?answertab=active#tab-top)

This worked great for me, however the string is delimited by a semi colon followed by a space.
If I specify the delimiter as a semi colon, after the first substring, the following substrings are preceded by a space.

However if I specify the delimiter as **'; '** (semi colon followed by space), the result is the same. I have increased the char length in the fn_Split function to 2 and 5, no change either.

Is it something I can alter in the Split function, or would it require another function to remove the preceding space after the Split function returns results?

Answer (score 0):

I just read about the LTRIM function to remove preceding spaces from a string. This will work for me as I am storing the Split results in a table so I can use the LTRIM in an Update statement.

Thanks for reading.